# Cannot open Visual Studio Code on my mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio Code on my Mac, but this sign keeps popping up whenever I try to open it. Deleted and installed 3 times but they all ended up with the same results. It says 'Visual Studio Code can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.'

[image]

Is there anybody who had the same issue or knows how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess that you're on Catalina. Apple requires all apps to be notarized (that is, confirmed to be of good reputation) otherwise they won't run.

You can try right clicking on the app and then clicking "open" which has proven to work for some/most users.

If that doesn't work you can move the app to the applications folder then run the following command in the terminal.

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app`

**EDIT**
This question is actually answered over on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457958/visual-studio-code-cant-be-opened-because-apple-cannot-check-it-for-malicious).